# Printing family tree until certain level | Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, tree

I am struggling with a recursive function that prints a family tree until a certain "depth/level".

I have defined class "Person" and each person has some descendant(s), so lets say:

```
>>> george.children
[<__main__.Person object at 0x000002C85FB45A58>]
>>> george.name
'George'
```

And I want to print the family tree in a way that each generation is separated by 4 whitespaces, for example:

```
>>> family_tree(george, level = 2)
George
    Michael
        Juliet
    Peter
        Mary
```

George is the level 0, then his two sons are level 1, etc.

Do you please have any ideas how to write this using recursion? I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use recursion. At each deeper level of recursion you should produce 4 more spaces. So for that purpose you could pass an argument `depth` that is increased at every recursive call.

Here is how you could do it:

```
# You'll have a class like this:
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.children = []
    def addChild(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)
        return self # to allow chaining

# The function of interest:
def family_tree(person, level = 2):
    def recurse(person, depth):
        if depth > level: return
        print (" " * (4 * depth) + person.name)
        for child in person.children:
            recurse(child, depth+1)
    recurse(person, 0)

# Sample data
george = Person("George").addChild(
    Person("Michael").addChild(
        Person("Juliet").addChild(
            Person("don't show me")
        )
    )
).addChild(
   Person("Peter").addChild(
        Person("Mary")
   )
)

# Call the function
family_tree(george)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That depth argument was what came to my mind as well but I never got right the incrementing of it, now I have it correct and it works like charm!